# IdentityServer, clients and user profile management

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, single-page-application, identityserver4, openid-connect

In instances where you have *multiple clients* and a *central IdentityServer 4* instance which handles user auth/n, how would you go about managing user profiles from individual clients?

**Current scenario:**

1. user clicks on manage profile
2. user is redirected to a custom manage claims page on IdentityServer which a) loads all claims in a form, b) allows user to mod such claims and c) updates them with new values
3. user is redirected to the referrer URL (which then retrieves
   these fresh claims via a token refresh which includes the profile
   scope) - although a redirect is not always possible, or is frowned
   upon from a design perspective (users' experience is broken since
   they are taken to a different location with a different design).

**Desired scenario:**

1. user clicks on manage profile
2. user is redirected to a profile page on the client itself (e.g. SPA or desktop), populated with info from the profile scope
3. user updates profile data, and client then makes an API call to IdentityServer to update the users' claims centrally
4. local claims are refreshed to reflect claims sent to Identity Server

**Main concern:** is this a sound approach architecturally speaking? Should user profiles (e.g. first/last name, gender, DoB, etc...) be managed by IdentityServer (via an API or own pages) or should these be stored centrally and used/managed by both IdentityServer (loaded as claims) and individual client apps? How would you go about tackling the desired scenario?

The closest info I got was in *method 3* discussed [here](http://bitoftech.net/2015/03/31/asp-net-web-api-claims-authorization-with-asp-net-identity-2-1/).

... however it's a 3+ year old doc, and am not sure what is recommended by oidc-client/IdentityServer 4 devs today.

Any insights would be highly appreciated.

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the main reason for the need of the second scenario could possibly be

> taken to a different location with different design

Is it?

If it's not, I don't see any benefit from repeating the same or similar claim update page on multiple client apps, if there are more than one.

If it is and you can't customize the page on your identity provider (the Identity Server), you can still have a single claim update page but just hosted outside of the Identity Server. This page (formally: the app that hosts it) would be the client of the identity provider as well as the client app that redirects here.

A benefit of this approach is that you could have a total control of how this page looks like, event make it conditional depending on the client.

> Should user profiles (e.g. first/last name, gender, DoB, etc...) be managed by IdentityServer (via an API or own pages) or should these be stored centrally and used/managed by both IdentityServe

There is no single answer to this as it totally depends on you actual business background.

It's even worse than you describe, you can have a hybrid system where some claims are shared by multiple subsystems but other subsystems have their own profiles not shared with any other subsystems and all these are integrated around one identity provider.

Comment: Hi Wiktor. Thanks for this, and for your insights (especially the "it gets worse" bit - makes me feel slightly better as it shows that there's no obvious answer). Yes, the different location is because each client app has its own design, and one is also a desktop app - therefore making it even more difficult to redirect users (although it's doable, it's rather messy). Let's say I'll keep using IdentityServer4 User/Claims table, are you aware of any way (e.g. UserInfo endpoint) by which I could update claims (a known set) from the client back to the IdServer? (e.g. using oidc-client.js)

Comment: From what I am aware of, the userinfo endpoint is intended to retrieve the user info, not update it (sorry if this is not accurate in newer releases). You'd have to provide a custom endpoint for that.

Comment: That's my understanding as well Wiktor. Using IdS4's claims table, managed from a third party app, seems rather messy to me. I rather wished I missed some API endpoint which could help me do that.

Comment: Unfortunately, you haven't. A quick peek info sources confirms that. I really hope someone has a clever idea here, though, so that you could resolve your issue.

Comment: I have opened up the issue [here as well](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/375). I doubt they'll get to it anytime soon however.

Comment: Considering how simple the implementation is, you could possibly fork their repo, implement the feature and create a pull request. In other words, do it for the community rather than wait if someone does it.

Comment: Possibly would be for the best. But it seems there's no right/wrong solution - and coupling IdS4 with Apps is not something I'd see as neat. We've gone for some redundancy, keeping IdS4 for authentication only. See update here: https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/375#issuecomment-317491814 .